# How to use Single port for 3 containers instead of 3 ports Python-Flask, PostgreSQL & Angular8 ? so I can use Docker Run instead of Docker Compose

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, flask, angular8

I have created three containers, one is for Python Flask application, second is for PostgreSQL db and third is for angular8. Im using Docker compose to run this. my question so each container has ports so total 3 ports. Is there a way I can use only one port to run this whole application like Docker Run instead of Docker Compose? All I want is a single port where this API can be called from anywhere.

Comment: You can delete the published `ports:` from the components you don’t need to access externally.  You can have three separate `docker run` commands for the three containers, but keeping your single `docker-compose up` is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want to be visible to the "outside" is the API, you can use the `--link` flag when calling `docker run`.  Basically, start up the PG container, then start up the Flask container, linking to PG, then start up the Angular container, linking to Flask.  However, the `--link` flag is a legacy feature, and may disappear sometime in the future.

Another option is to create a network with `docker network create` and make sure your three containers are all using that same network.  They should all be able to communicate with each other in this way, and you just need to publish the API port so that other apps can use your API.

I'm not sure what your requirements are, but `docker-compose` is generally the cleaner way to do it, as it helps you achieve consistency in your automations.